# Java Micro Edition (J2ME) - Delete element from Record Store

Tags: java, java-me, midp, rms

I have a record store which holds a list of shopping items i am currently serialising the data like so

```
** (inside) ItemClass **            
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(byteOutputStream);

dataOutputStream.writeUTF(getOwner());
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(getItemName());
dataOutputStream.writeInt(getQuantity());

dataOutputStream.close();

return byteOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

This byte array is then written to the record store like so (using for loop for each id)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= shoppingListStore.getNumRecords(); i++)
{
     byte[] itemRecord = shoppingListStore.getRecord(i);
     newItemObject.fromByteArray(itemRecord);
     userShoppingList.append(newItemObject.getItemName() + " " + newItemObject.getQuantity() + " " + newItemObject.getOwner(), null);
}
```

The problem comes from using the ID to treverse through the record store as this may change from deletion etc and as such i keep geting invalid id being thrown. I know i cannot use For each ItemObj : Recordstore so how do i treverse through the record store without having to worry about ids ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `recordStore.enumerateRecords(null, null, false)`

Then use `RecordEnumeration.hasNextElement()` and `RecordEnumeration.nextRecord()`